# PHP passing 'fetch_array()' to variable array to use elsewhere in code?

Tags: php, oracle

Hey guys im trying to get some data from a query (oracle) to pass into a varaible that i can use later in different fuctions/queries . can someone help me fix my code?

```
$conn = oci_connect('asdasddasddasd');
$RCB = array();

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, "  SELECT WR.REQST_NO                          
                            FROM P_D.WORK_REQST WR                      
                            WHERE WR.WORK_REQST_STATUS_CD = 'PLAN' AND WR.DEPT_CD ='ISNG'       

                            ");
oci_execute($stid);



while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    // Use the uppercase column names for the associative array indices

$GLOBAL['RCB'] = $row['REQST_NO'];


}

print_r($RCB);

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

how come this doesn't work?

Comment: `$GLOBALS` with an `S`... and you overwrite it each time, so just append a new row `$GLOBALS['RCB'][] = $row['REQST_NO'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the while loop to build a new array.

i.e. :

```
$rcb_array = array();
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    $rcb_array[] = $row['REQST_NO']; // for each $row, add a new item in $rcb_array with 'REQST_NO' value
}

print_r($rcb_array); // then use the new array outside the loop and do what ever you want with it
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You're welcome. Thanks for validate this answer if it solved your question.

Comment: i have a part 2 to this problem, should i post here or make a new thread?

Comment: i couldn't post a new question so i edited this post.. any help would be appreciated

Comment: @DJRCB I feel that I've fallen onto deaf ears. I don't see a green tick next to this answer as you originally stated [*"thank you. this works! – DJRCB 39 mins ago"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586516/php-passing-fetch-array-to-variable-array-to-use-elsewhere-in-code#comment72305295_42586582) - Edit: you've accepted it ;-)

Comment: Thank you @DJRCB. Good luck. Will certainly see your new question in a while.

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii-. ; )

Comment: @JazZ welcome. Always glad to make the system work as it should and as it was written for ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
    $req_arr[] = $row['REQST_NO'];
}
```

print_r($req_arr)